# Visual Studio 2010 IntelliTrace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

As you know IntelliTrace technology just available on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate version, and I accidentally installed Premium version, so I cant use IntelliTrace. Is there any extension which does same/similar job with IntelliTrace? Or should I remove this version, and install Ultimate? :)

Comment: Can't you install Ultimate on top of Premium to upgrade? Either way, it seems *far* easier and less time-consuming to reinstall than to hunt around for a poorly supported (and non existent) extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you own Ultimate and it's just a case of reinstalling, why would you not?

I see little reason to hunt around for plugins which may not have the exact same functionality. IMHO it's a bit of a time waste.

Comment: I really dont have time to re-install, thats why I'm searching some extensions :)

Comment: It'll be faster to reinstall than it will be to find an extension. Google proves that.

Comment: hmm it looks there is no way. Thanks.